# Is this syntax good form: "PI / (double) (i - j)" in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, types

EDIT — Actually the syntax was not good form, because there is a superlative statement, which is a fair reason for me being confused, whether it is good form, and if so, why. It's my first C code ever, grafting 9 research journal algorithms inside 1000 line code from 1989.

What is a double-type in between brackets:

```
    PI / (double) (i - j);
```

Is it to ensure that the result is a float?

The bigger expression statement is:

```
xi[i] = xi[i] + 2.0 * xr[j] / PI / (double) (i - j);
```

Comment: Had it been me writing the expression, I think I would have written: `xi[i] += (2.0 * xr[j]) / (PI * (i - j));` — the cast is superfluous, since the dividend is clearly a `double` expression because `2.0` is a `double` constant, and in all probability, `PI` is a `double` constant too.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "antiquated" about it, it's a normal C type cast.

Assuming `PI` is of a floating-point type, [which seems safe](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj55veMm-3LAhXK3SwKHYzmDQoQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fio9.com%2F5880792%2Fthe-eccentric-crank-who-tried-to-legislate-the-value-of-pi&usg=AFQjCNF1hchYtI5ST9nyPbZfa-z-GnD22w&sig2=4PAbmuKBcNc87TEbiOOs2w), the division will be performed using the type of `PI` thanks to promotion.

So, the cast might (depending on the context) have value if `PI` is of type `float`, but you really want the division to happen at `double` precision. Of course, it would make more sense to actually cast `PI` in that case ...

Comment: Ok no worries, the code is 27 years old, so i figured that it was fairy old :)

Comment: `PI` *could* be of type `float`. If `i - j` was of type `float` or an integer type, the cast to `double` would *not* be pointless.